# execute Sqlite3 command line tool from code

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run the sqlite.exe tool as a process in my c# code in order to read a sql from a file.

If I run the sqLite3 tool in powershell then it works fine (sqlite3.exe "mydatabase.db" ".read mySql.sql")

But when I run the sqlite3 tool from my c# code as a process, then nothing happens to mydatabase.db. It's still 0b when sqlite3 terminates.
I get no error message, the output from the sqlite3.exe is an empty string and the exit code is 1 (verified in the exit event). Does anyone have a clue why the database.db why the records in the .sql file is not added to the .db file?.

```
using (Process pProcess = new Process())
        {
            pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sqlLite3ExePath;
            pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{sqLitePath2}\" \".read {sqlPath}\"";;
            pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;//System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;//true; //not diplay a windows
            pProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            pProcess.Exited += PProcess_Exited;
            pProcess.Start();
            string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
            pProcess.WaitForExit();

            Debug.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: You have what looks to be a very important line commented out.

Comment: Try reading the StandardError to end instead - if the tool has encountered errors and pumped messages they may not be in standard output, but in the error stream. Note of course you'll need to redirectstandarderror= true

Comment: Why don't you just load the script into your app and execute it using the c# SQLite driver, like you're gonna be doing for everything else?

Comment: @Shawn, your right. I commented that line to check if I the standard output stream worked as it should, and I forgot to remove the // before posting.

Comment: @CaiusJard that solved it, there was a file can't be found error in the error stream. the \ that separates the directories was removed since the string was parsed twice (first when sending it as an argument, and then it was parsed again by sqlite3.exe)

Comment: @CaiusJard I want to leverage this code to export a sql server ce database to sqLite. I found a tool by ErikEj that outputs sql and I thought that using the sqLite3.exe would be the easiest and fastest way to parse the sql into sqLite. But you are probably right, I will look into the sqLite library. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CaiusJard said in the comments, an error was passed in the error stream. Adding the following lines told me that my path was wrong.

```
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
string error = pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
```

The path divider "\" was removed since the path was parsed twice. Once setting the argument, and once when it was read by the tool. Replacing "\" with "/" in my paths did the trick